# Javascript variables become undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble getting my code to work. I load and parse a JSON file using an XMLHttpRequest which works fine, but after my setup() function I can't call any other functions on any of the variables I've defined such as spriteDictionary - even though in the various setup functions I can read these variables and all looks good.

Any thoughts? In the sample below when I call console.log(parsedJSON); it comes up undefined which is odd since I can read the contents of it in my setup code. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
</body>

<script type="application/x-javascript">
var parsedJSON;   
var ctx;
var canvas;
var atlas;
var sprites = [];
var spriteDictionary = {};

var sprite = function(name, atl, x, y, w, h) {
    this.name = name;
    this.atlas = atl;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.cx =  -w/2.0;
    this.cy = -h/2.0;

}

function setup() {
    var body = document.getElementById("body");

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 1200;
    canvas.height =720;
    body.appendChild(canvas);

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,1200,720);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","game_gfx.json",true);
    xhr.onload = function (){
        parsedJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        load_assets(parsedJSON);
    }
    xhr.send();
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

}

function load_assets(pJSON) {
    atlas = new Image();
    atlas.onload = function() {
        console.log("atlas loaded");
    }
    atlas.src= pJSON['meta']['image'];
    var frame;
    for (var i in pJSON['frames']){
        frame = pJSON['frames'][i];
        spriteDictionary[frame['filename']] =  new sprite(frame['filename'],atlas,frame['frame']['x'],frame['frame']['y'],frame['frame']['w'],frame['frame']['h']);
        i++;
    }
}

setup();

console.log(parsedJSON);

</script>


</html>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `type="application/x-javascript"`? Just leave it out.

Comment: The purpose was that komodo-edit automatically threw it in and I was too lazy to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not treat asynchronous Call like it is synchronous.

You are calling the console.log line before the Ajax call returns.

A simple console.log statement in the onload listener would show you that.

```
xhr.onload = function (){
    console.log("I AM HERE!");
    ...
```

The log would look like

```
undefined
"I AM HERE"
"atlas loaded"
```

Comment: Ahhh Thanks. so my XHR hasn't finsished when I'm calling the other commands. I appreciate the help.